# Analogy between metric space completion and algebraic closure

Tags: ct.category-theory, galois-theory, metric-spaces

I've noticed some similarities between the story of completing a metric space and taking algebraic closure of a field. My question is whether these two stories can be generalized.

### Metric space

Fix a metric space $(X, d_X)$. Consider isometries from it to other metric spaces (i.e. the under category).

1. Every isometry $(X, d_X) \to (Y, d_Y)$ is continuous and injective.
2. Given isometry $\varphi : (X, d_X) \to (Y, d_Y)$, say the closure is the map $\overline{\varphi} : (X, d_X) \to \left(\overline{\varphi(X)}, d_Y|_{\overline{\varphi(X)}}\right)$.
3. Taking closure (2) is idempotent.
4. Say isometry $\varphi : (X, d_X) \to (Y, d_Y)$ is "dense" if $\varphi = \overline{\varphi}$ (2) (i.e. the range is dense in the codomain).
5. Say $(Z,d_Z)$ is "complete" if every Cauchy sequence converges.
6. If isometry $(X, d_X) \to (Y, d_Y)$ is dense (4) and isometry $(X, d_X) \to (Z, d_Z)$ has complete codomain (5) then there is an isometry $(Y, d_Y) \to (Z, d_Z)$ making the diagram commute (i.e. a morphism in the under category).
7. Say isometry $(X, d_X) \to (Y, d_Y)$ is a "completion" if it is dense (4) and has complete domain (5).
8. Given isometry $\varphi: (X, d_X) \to (Z, d_Z)$ with complete codomain (5), we can take its closure $\overline{\varphi}$ (2) to get a completion (7).

### Field

Fix a base field $F$. Consider homomorphisms from it to other fields (i.e. the under category).

1. Every field homomorphism $F \to K$ is injective.
2. Given homomorphism $i : F \to K$, say the closure is the map $\bar{i} : F \to \text{integral closure of $i(F)$ in $K$}$.
3. Taking closure (2) is idempotent.
4. Say homomorphism $i : F \to K$ is "algebraic" if $i = \overline{i}$ (2) (i.e. every element of $K$ is algebraic over $F$).
5. Say $L$ is "algebraically closed" if every non-constant polynomial over $L$ has a root in $L$.
6. If $F \to K$ is algebraic (4) and $F \to L$ has algebraically closed domain (5) then there is a homomorphism $K \to L$ making the diagram commute (i.e. a morphism in the under category).
7. Say $F \to K$ is an "algebraic closure" if it is algebraic (4) and the codomain is algebraically closed (5).
8. Given homomorphism $F \to L$ with algebraically closed codomain (5), we can take its closure (2) to get an algebraic closure (7).

### My thoughts

The maps in the metric space scenario are unique while the maps in the field scenario are highly non-unique. So reflective subcategory might be able to deal with the first one but not the second one; if we consider finite separable extensions then Galois category might be able to deal with the second one but certainly not the first one. However, I do not know much about Galois categories.

Comment: I think this might be more appropriate for math.stackexchange.

Comment: If the question really is "which NLab page deals with a common generalisation of reflective subcategories and Galois categories" then maybe MO is the right place for it. It's an appealing analogy but I don't know a common generalisation. One construction is an adjoint functor, but I don't think the other is. This question is a bit more confusing than I want it to be.

Comment: The higher inductive types of the HoTT book provide one common generalization, as elaborated in the discussion of the reals in sec 11.3.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some thoughts about common generalizations.  First let $e$ be an object of a category $C$.

- $e$ is **initial** if for every object $x\in C$ there is a unique morphism $e\to x$.
- $e$ is **[weakly initial](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weakly+initial+object)** if for every object $x\in C$ there exists a (not necessarily unique) morphism $e\to x$.
- $e$ is **Galois-initial** if it is weakly initial, and in addition for any two parallel morphisms $f,g:e\to x$ there is a unique morphism $h:e\to e$ with $f h = g$.  (It follows that $h$ is an isomorphism, since we also have a unique $k$ with $g k = f$, and uniqueness gives $h k = k h = 1_e$.)

I just made up the term "Galois-initial"; suggestions for a better name (or even better, literature references) are welcome.  In the terminology of [these slides](http://www.math.muni.cz/~rosicky/papers/leeds2.pdf) a Galois initial object is a "poly-initial object" that is a singleton set.  Clearly every initial object is Galois initial.

Now let $D\hookrightarrow C$ be a subcategory.

- $D$ is **reflective** in $C$ if for every $x\in C$ the comma category $(x\downarrow D)$ has an initial object.
- $D$ is **weakly reflective** in $C$ if for every $x\in C$ the comma category $(x\downarrow D)$ has a weakly initial object.
- $D$ is **Galois-reflective** in $C$ if for every $x\in C$ the comma category $(x\downarrow D)$ has a Galois initial object.

Of course as you say, your first example exhibits complete metric spaces as a reflective subcategory of all metric spaces.  I believe your second example exhibits algebraically closed fields as a Galois-reflective subcategory of all fields.  Thus, since every reflection is in particular a Galois-reflection, both are examples of Galois-reflections (hence *a fortiori* both examples of weak reflections).

This definition describes the relationship between the two categories, but not the common situation of "closure inside an ambient object".  I believe that can be described in terms of an [orthogonal factorization system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+factorization+system) $(E,M)$.  In your first example, $E$ is the dense inclusions and $M$ is the closed inclusions, while in your second example $E$ is the algebraic extensions and $M$ is the integrally closed ones.

In a category with a terminal object, every orthogonal factorization system induces a reflective subcategory consisting of those objects $x$ for which $x\to 1$ lies in $M$, with the $(E,M)$-factorization of $x\to 1$ providing the reflection; but your categories don't have terminal objects!  Instead we can do something like define an object $x$ to be **$E$-injective** if for any $E$-morphism $f:u\to v$ and any morphism $g:u\to x$ there is an extension $h:v\to x$ with $h f = g$.  Note that this is your points (6), and that if there is a terminal object these are precisely the objects such that $x\to 1$ lies in $M$.

**Lemma:** If all morphisms are mono, then every morphism with $E$-injective domain lies in $M$.

**Proof:** Given $x\to y$ with $x$ being $E$-injective, factor it as $x\to z\to y$ with $x\to z$ in $E$ and $z\to y$ in $M$.  Then $E$-injectivity supplies a retraction $z\to x$, which is an isomorphism since it is is mono; thus $x\to y$ is isomorphic to $z\to y$ and hence also in $M$.  $\Box$

**Theorem:** If all morphisms are mono and every object $x$ admits an $E$-morphism $\eta_x: x\to \hat{x}$ where $\hat{x}$ is $E$-injective, then the $E$-injective objects are Galois-reflective.

**Proof:** Suppose $f,g:\hat{x}\to y$ are morphisms with $f \eta_x = g \eta_x$, where $y$ is also $E$-injective.  By the lemma, they are both in $M$.  Then the unique lifting property in the commutative square $f \eta_x = g \eta_x$ gives $h:\hat{x}\to\hat{x}$ with $h \eta_x = \eta_x$ and $f h = g$, which is exactly what we wanted.  $\Box$

Note that an $E$-morphism to an $E$-injective is your points (7).  Finally, if $y$ is an $E$-injective and $z\to y$ lies in $M$, then $z$ is also $E$-injective. Thus if $x\to y$ is a morphism with $y$ an $E$-injective, then by $(E,M)$-factoring it we obtain an $E$-morphism from $x$ to an $E$-injective; this is your points (8).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if essentially this situation, or something very like it, has already been considered in [categorical Galois theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+Galois+theory), but I'm not sufficiently familiar with that literature to point to where.

Comment: Regarding terminology, MO points me to the following related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/256382/49 which is about "Galois-initial" objects minus uniqueness of $h$ (which then requires specifying explicitly that it is an isomorphism).