# Weakening of terminal object in a category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, slice-categories

I’ve come across a category $\mathcal{C}$ recently with an object $T$ such that any other object $X$ has a map $f:X\rightarrow T$, and for any two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow T$, there exists a (not necessarily unique) automorphism $\sigma$ of $X$ such that $g=f\circ \sigma$. It’s easy to check that if a category has such $T$ with this property, it’s unique up to non unique isomorphism.

I’m wondering what the name for this property of $T$ (or $\mathcal{C}$) is, and what relation it implies between $\mathcal{C}$ and the slice category $\mathcal{C}/_T$.

Comment: Does [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256382/what-are-nearly-initial-objects-really-called) answer your question?

Comment: Fantastic! Sorry for the dupe question.

Comment: @ChrisH it’s not a duplicate, notice that the linked question puts the automorphism in the other object.

Comment: Oh true, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: There is probably some description of things in terms of the forgetful fibration $\mathcal{C}/T\to\mathcal{C}$…